# Replacing the seq IDs of fasta file based on the new IDs from a list

Tags: awk, sed, perl

I have a fasta file and I want to replace the seq Ids (description lines) with new and extended IDs. This is the format of fasta file:

```
>3C-assembly|contig_74
TAATAAAAAATATTTTTTTAATTGACCCTAACCAAATCCTGAACCTAACCGTAACACTGA
>3C-assembly|contig_75
TAATAAAAAATATTTTTTTAATTGACCCTAACCAAATCCTGAACCTAACCGTAACACTGA
>3C-assembly|contig_76
TAATAAAAAATATTTTTTTAATTGACCCTAACCAAATCCTGAACCTAACCGTAACACTGA
...................
```

and want to achieve a new fasta with the following format:

```
>Scaffold_001 [Sex=Female] [Unplaced scaffold]
TAATAAAAAATATTTTTTTAATTGACCCTAACCAAATCCTGAACCTAACCGTAACACTGA
>Scaffold_002 [Sex=Female] [Unplaced scaffold]
TAATAAAAAATATTTTTTTAATTGACCCTAACCAAATCCTGAACCTAACCGTAACACTGA
>Scaffold_003 [Sex=Female] [Unplaced scaffold]
TAATAAAAAATATTTTTTTAATTGACCCTAACCAAATCCTGAACCTAACCGTAACACTGA
....................
```

It means that, for example, the 3C-assembly|contig_74 should be replaced by Scaffold_001 [Sex=Female] [Unplaced scaffold]. For this purpose, I built a text file including two columns (Tab-delimited) connecting these two IDS:

```
3C-assembly|contig_74   Scaffold_001 [Sex=Female] [Unplaced scaffold]
3C-assembly|contig_75   Scaffold_002 [Sex=Female] [Unplaced scaffold]
3C-assembly|contig_76   Scaffold_003 [Sex=Female] [Unplaced scaffold]
......................
```

Do you have any idea how can I use this text file to replace IDs in my fasta file.
Thank you

Comment: Yes, Thank you. The header lines at fasta starts with >.  The next line is sequences e.g. TAATCGA...

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'\t' '
  NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
  /^>/{ 
    id=a[substr($0, 2)]
    if (id!=""){ print ">" id; next }
  }
  1
' textfile file.fasta
```

First, read the text file containing the mapping and save the second field in array `a` using the first field as index. Skip to the `next` record.

Then read the fasta file. If the record starts with `>`, look up the new id from the array by removing the first character from the current record (`substr($0, 2)`) and using this value as array index.
If the id is not empty, print `>` and the id and skip to the `next` record.

The `1` prints the current record (the sequences or non-matching ids).

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'\t' '
    NR==FNR { map[">"$1] = ">"$2; next }
    $0 in map { $0 = map[$0] }
    { print }
' mapfile fastafile
```